# File Permissions from .dd image

Tags: mount, permissions, dd

I am trying to access files from a .dd image made of my MacBook Pro.  Not the complete disk with the recovery partition and everything, just the partition where my files are.  I can mount it in Ubuntu using:

udisksctl loop-setup -r -f image.dd

I have been able to peruse and open my files except ones like Pictures, Music, Movies, Downloads, etc.  These are standard Mac file system folders, not created by me, and I get the error:

This location could not be displayed.  You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "Pictures".

How do I set these permissions to view all files or do I have to re-image my Mac and do it differently?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: General idea would be to put "sudo" in front of your command you use to view the contents. Mostlikely you are using another user-id so you are not allowed to view them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rinzwind and liquidat, thanks for your help and suggestions.

Nothing seemed to work, using sudo, etc. Took a total of nine days to find answer. Knew I was working with Ubuntu 14.04 and a MacBook Pro dd image.  Knew I could mount image and access non-standard file system files but not standard file system folders.

This is how you can do it:

Open Ubuntu Software Center, search for and install the package “gnome-system-tools” (without quotes).  Or (best and preferred method) open a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t) and enter

sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools

After installation, you can run users-admin from the terminal to open Users and Groups or access them via Administration > Users and Groups.

Use the + sign and create a new user.  The New User you create needs to match the settings on the Mac, Mac image, or Mac formatted hard drive are trying to access.  For example, if your user name is Frank and your password is MyPassword on the Mac, then you need to use these settings when creating your New User.

Click on your new user and change your account type to Administrator.

Click on Advanced Settings > User Privileges.  Check all boxes that apply.  Click on Advanced.  Change the User ID from 1000 (or whatever it is) to 501 (which is where Macs start their user id's, if your Mac user id is different change accordingly).

Note, you may have had to unlock your user group in order to make any changes, depending on which way you accessed it.  Unlock is located in the top right.  Click and enter password to unlock or lock.  You will see what I am talking about if needed.

Close out of everything and restart.  You should see your Original User and the New User you just created.  If not you will have to go back into Original User and change the UID_MIN from 1000 to 501 for the New User to show in the welcome menu.  Sorry, this is what I didn't save.  You will have to google:  How to change uid in Ubuntu 14.04 (or whatever linux version you are using.  This is important.  All the instructions that worked for me were specific to Ubuntu 14.04.)

For the final test, I logged into my New User and mounted my Mac image.dd and TA-DAAAA!!!

It worked!  I was able to access all the files on my MacBook Pro dd image.

Also Note that I did not need read and write access.  I only wanted read access to recover files.  If you need write access then you will have to research it further.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS usually usees a variant of the HFS+ filesystem [HFS on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus). This does support user rights - which are respected in Linux. Since the user id of your Ubuntu user and of your MacOS user is most likely different, you are not allowed to access the files.

So as already mentioned, the way to go would be to access the files with super user rights - using sudo, for example.